# How to detect if a firefox extension is installed

Tags: javascript, firefox

I Need a javascript to check if a firefox extension (not plugin) is installed.

I've created a clickonce application and I need my users can open the clickonce app with firefox, I know there is an extension from Microsoft to to this, but I need to know if that extension is installed, if not, I want to send to my users to the correct url to get the extension.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real way to do this outside of creating your own extension that reads other extensions is if the extension you are looking for injects something into the global variable scope that you can detect the presence of.

`if('someExtensionObject' in window){ ... }`